# not getting return from function when 'monthly' or 'annually' is misspelt

Tags: python-3.x

Works fine unless annually or monthly is misspelt, I do not know why.
The get_valid_options(options) does not seems to be returning when called. Any help will be greatly appleciated:)

```
    hv = float(input('Enter house value: $'))
    valid = is_valid(hv)
    options = input('Paying monthly or annually: ')
    valid_option = get_valid_options(options)
    if options == 'monthly':
        print('Monthly: ',paying_monthly(valid,options))     
    if options == 'annually':
        print('Annually: ',paying_annually(valid,options))
def is_valid(hv):
    while hv < 0:
        print('House value cannot be negative.')
        hv = float(input('Enter house value: $'))
    return hv

def get_valid_options(options):
    while options != 'monthly' and options != 'annually':
        print("Error")
        options = input('Paying monthly or annually: ')
    return options         
def paying_monthly(valid,options):
        r = 0.045
        monthly = (r*valid)/12.0
        return monthly
def paying_annually(valid,options):
        r = 0.03
        annually = (r*valid)
        return annually
```

Comment: I mean the program works fine unless monthly or annually is misspelt. I don't know why line 5 does not work.

Comment: Please do not post code as images -- copy the code into your question and format it as code. Also, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65272625/edit) your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: costaparas, Thanks. Can you have a look now

Comment: Where is your `input()` function?

Comment: I did not use user an input function...is it mandatory?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
if options == 'monthly':
    print('Monthly: ', paying_monthly(valid, options))     
if options == 'annually':
    print('Annually: ', paying_annually(valid, options))
```

you should be checking `valid_option` rather than `options`. Change it to:

```
if valid_option == 'monthly':
    print('Monthly: ', paying_monthly(valid, options))     
if valid_option == 'annually':
    print('Annually: ', paying_annually(valid, options))
```

Otherwise, your code *only* works as expected if the user enters a valid option on the first go.